# How to use Redirect::intended in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want the route to bypass authentication filter after successfully login. So I use `Redirect::intended`. But it makes problem. Here is my code

In LoginController@doLogin

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {   
 return Redirect::intended("home.index");
}
```

In Routes

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
        Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController');
});
```

My routes
[image: my routes image]

If I put the the home resource route without the `auth` filter, then it will work. (Not redirect to login route.).That code is given below

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController');
}); /* No Problem with this code */
```

But I want to work with `auth` filter.I'm using laravel 4.
Please help me...

Comment: So what is your problem? You are redirect to `/login` everytime?

Comment: @Andreyco Yes it will redirect to /login everytime. But i don't want to redirect to /login after successfully match the username and password-`(Auth::attempt($credentials))`. If we use `Redirect::intended`, it will ignore the authentication-(`auth`) filter of the given route. But it will not working in my project.

Comment: Everything looks fine -- are you sure this isn't a cookie issue of some sort? If you're able to login and hit the "intended" code line, your authentication is successful. If that is disappearing, it sounds like a cookie issue, perhaps from a browser plugin.

Comment: That means cookie/session is problem here. Somehow, your app cannot keep user logged in. Try to dump all cookies and session, or do `dd(Auth::user());`, to see whether user login state is changed after `Auth::attempt($credentials);`

Comment: @Artsemis Thanks, It is a session problem. I fixed it.

Comment: @Andreyco Thanks, It is a session problem. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently I use this:

in filter.php

```
Route::filter('sentry', function() {

    if (!Sentry::check())
    {
            return Redirect::route('authLogin');
    }
});
```

so in route.php

```
Route::get('auth/login/', array('as' => 'authLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login'));
Route::post('auth/login/', array('as' => 'authLogin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login'));

Route::group(array('before' => 'sentry'), function() {

    Route::get('user/', array('as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'UserController@index'));
    Route::get('user/index', array('as' => 'userIndex', 'uses' => 'UserController@index'));
});
```

[I preffer named routes.](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes)